# libQGL in Qt application

Tags: qt, opengl

I use libQGL in a Qt project to make a point cloud viewer. The problem is that, with more points (more than 300.000), the interaction with viewer (rotations, translations, zoom) is slow. How can I fix this?

Comment: 300K of points is trivial to render for even a basic GPU.  You need to provide more detail in how you are getting the data to the GPU, and what you doing per frame update - preferably with code examples.

Answer (score 1):

render less points while you are zooming/translating/rotating. when rendering point clouds you can render every third point by multiplying the stride of the vertex attribute buffer by 3

(using the QOpenGLShaderProgram methods)

```
void PointCloud::paintGL(){
    glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT|GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);
    pointProgram->bind ();
    points.bind ();
    if(transforming){
        pointProgram->setAttributeBuffer (pointLoc, GL_FLOAT, offsetof (PointStruct, data), 3,sizeof(PointStruct)*3);
    } else {
        pointProgram->setAttributeBuffer (pointLoc, GL_FLOAT, offsetof (PointStruct, data), 3,sizeof(PointStruct));
    }
    CHECK_GL_ERR;

    if(transforming){
        pointProgram->setAttributeBuffer (pointCol, GL_FLOAT, offsetof (GrabberPointXYZIT,color), 3,sizeof(GrabberPointXYZIT)*3);
    } else {
        pointProgram->setAttributeBuffer (pointCol, GL_FLOAT, offsetof (GrabberPointXYZIT,color), 3,sizeof(GrabberPointXYZIT));
    }
    CHECK_GL_ERR;
    pointProgram->enableAttributeArray (pointLoc);
    pointProgram->enableAttributeArray (pointCol);
    pointProgram->setUniformValue (mvpLoc, pMat*vMat);

    glDrawArrays (GL_POINTS,0, numPoints);
    CHECK_GL_ERR;


    pointProgram->release ();
    points.release ();
}
```